# How to search for tag in certain div, excluding other similarly named div?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this site: http://800notes.com/Phone.aspx/1-717-746-7214

To get this info: "23 May 2017"

But the news articles on the side of the page are named similarly, so I cannot single out the tags I'm looking for, and it skews my results. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

I'm trying to make sure I don't get the "datetime" tags on the right side of the page, which are linked to articles and discussion boards.

Here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
datePre = soup.find('div', id='oos_px')
soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(datePre), 'lxml')
dateList = soup.find_all('time')
endingString = str(dateList[-1])
timeStart = endingString.index('\"') + 1
timeEnd = timeStart + 10
dateString = endingString[timeStart:timeEnd]
```

I'm being told that the list is out of range? It should produce a resultset which I can search through correct? I've been boggling over this all day and it's driving me insane haha. Thanks to all who venture here.

```
global dateString
soup.select(".oos_contletList time")
dateList = soup.find_all('time')
endingString = str(dateList[-1])
```

Updated code that should work but is still grabbing the latest post on the news sites on the sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this with beautiful soup, but the css selector below should be correct.
Tested the selector with chrome.

```
for elm in soup.select(".oos_contletList time"):
    print(elm.text)
```

I was trying to use the [:not(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)) css selector to exlude the ones you mentioned.  I'll post back if I get that working.

Comment: Thank you so much let me try what you said.

Comment: It's weird but its grabbing "2017-07-19" instead of the actual content, any ideas?
Check my edit on my post for code update :)

Comment: you're looking for the innerHTML in that case.  There is likely a beaufiful soup method to do that.  i'll edit my answer with some pseudo code

Comment: Thank you!! You're awesome.

Comment: Sure, lemme just do a test run.